# TinyMCE: синхронизация содержимого редактора с другим элементом на странице

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Ищу решения для синхронизации текста между редактором и полем "textarea".

T.E. Чтобы при редактировании данные из редактора автоматически синхронизировались(сохранялись) с полем "textarea"

```
...    
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea", 

...

<textarea id="textarea" name="content">Место для сохранения(синхронизации)</textarea>
```

На примере редактора на стаке - сверху редактор, внизу "textarea" с результатом редактирования, встроенная функция tinyMCE не подходит.

Код ниже выводит в консоль, но не в элемент, где ошибка?

```
setup: function(editor) {
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
    editor.on('change', function(e) {
        console.debug(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
        document.getElementById('#textarea').innerHTML = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
    });
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете ввиду. Но может это поможет - http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:event.tinymce.Editor.change, http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:autosave

Comment: Опишите подробно, по пунктам, чего вы хотите.

Comment: Чтобы при изменении в поле редактора код из редактора попадал непосредственно в поле `<textarea>`

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Да только ник мой через @ не укзали и мне уведомление не пришло, что на комментарий ответили. `textarea` - это поле редактирования текста, а на stackoverflow мы редактируем сообщение именно в чистом `textarea` в котором отображается некоторое подобие исходного кода сообщения, а как это будет выглядеть - уже ниже. TinyMCE - WYSYWIG редактор - его смысл в том, что он сразу показывает что получится, как MS Word, а исходный код скрывает, снизу будет отображаться тоже самое, что и внутри (на SO это совсем не так). Вам это нужно?

Comment: @RussCoder Я понимаю что он сразу отображает, но он держит код внутри редактора и никак не влияет на исходный код страницы, а мне именно нужен код внутри страницы для дальнейшего парсинга

Comment: Я вас понял. Постараюсь сейчас помочь. Только вам нужна не `textarea`, а просто `<div></div>.
P.S: теперь уведомление пришло )

Comment: @RussCoder мне не обязательно чтобы этот код был виден на странице, главное чтобы он присутствовал в исходнике. Просто не нашел адекватного компонента для C# и решил выйти из положения таким способом. Но после редактирования мне нужен чистый код без редактора, с этим я знаю как справиться )

Comment: @RussCoder в общем что-то сам накидал, в консоль выводит, а вот в страницу никак... `    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('change', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('#textarea').innerHTML = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
        });
    }`

Comment: Обновил ответ - описал вашу ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипт установки tinyMCE - InitTinyMCE.js

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#forTinyMCE',
    width: 700,
    height: 100,
    resize: false,
    plugins: 'link emoticons table code image',
    menubar: "edit insert view format tools",
    toolbar1: 'fontselect fontsizeselect |  bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote ',
    toolbar2: 'code | undo redo | removeformat subscript superscript | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify',
    toolbar3: 'table | bold italic underline strikethrough | link unlink | emoticons | image responsivefilemanager',
    relative_urls: false,
    setup: function (editor) { //при установке tinyMCE
        editor.on('NodeChange', function (e) { // при вставке
            var view = document.getElementById("view"); // нашли поле отображения
            view.innerHTML = editor.getContent();  // синхронизировались
        });
        editor.on('keypress', function (e) { // при нажатии клавиши
            var view = document.getElementById("view");
            view.innerHTML = editor.getContent();
        });
    }
});
```

HTML страница

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js" defer></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jslib/InitTinyMCE.js" defer></script>
        <title>Пример использования tinymce</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="margin: 0 25%; position: relative">  
            <form action="post/postPool.php" name="textForm" method="post">
                <textarea name="text" id="forTinyMCE" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;">Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>    
                <!--<input type="submit" value="Upload">-->
            </form>           
            <div id="view" style="width: 700px; height: 200px; background: lightgoldenrodyellow; overflow: auto">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Под редактором поле, с которым синхронизируется редактор.
Идея: просто обрабатываем события нажатия клавиши и изменения поля (если текст вставляют обработчик нажатия не сработает) и перезаписываем содержимое редактора в специальное поле.

P.S: Можно использовать событие `change`, но оно генерируется не при каждом нажатии клавиши и не при каждом изменении текста в редакторе.

Update: код `document.getElementById('#textarea')` неверен. Надо писать  `document.getElementById('textarea')` без `#`. И лучше такие id не использовать. Пишите хотя бы `mytextarea`.

Answer (score 1):

результат работы редактора можно получить в js с помощью

```
tinyMCE.get(‘textarea′).getContent();
```

Comment: Нужен не результат, а именно синхронизация с полем "textarea"

Comment: так а что мешает положить это результат в textarea? или вы хотите непрерывную синхронизацию? я, например, перекладываю, когда собираюсь отправлять результат на сервер. функция автосохранения тоже может это сделать. А на каждое изменение - ресурсов многомне кажется надо

Comment: ну у меня на самом деле шаманство сейчас, нормального wysiwyg Редактора для c# не нашел вот и развлекаюсь. В жаба скрипте слабоват :( а с авто сохранением какая-то беда. по этому именно непрерывная синхронизация. Как мне подсказали лучше ковырять в этом направлении `    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('change', function(e) {
            
        });
    }`

Comment: хорошо, этим в запустите фукцию на каждое изменение в тексте. что дальше? мой ответ позволит вам взять из редактора результат его работы. хоть на каждом изменении, хоть перед сохранением :)

Comment: Это я понял, но тут и "завис" у меня с JavaScript мало опыта :(